# Javascript and HTML5 File API - problems getting file correctly routed to function

Tags: javascript, html, binary, filemaker

I am wondering how to define a file reference for an HTML5 'file' object, to be used as input to a JavaScript function that will convert the file into Base64 encoding, WITHOUT using an interactive file input element.  I have seen the HTML5Rocks examples, and numerous others, but they all use an `<input type=file>` element to read and gather inputs about the file to operate on. I am intending to take image files (i.e. binary) as input, and output Base64 strings. (Perhaps it is obvious, but I am new to the HTML5 and JavaScript worlds)

Some of my reading seems to indicate that this isn't possible for security reasons: JS would then be able to run arbitrary files. I wanted to double check.

What is the output of the 'file' input type? Can I manually mimic it in some way?  (I found one reference here about just directly including the file itself inside the JS, but can you do that with a binary file?  Frankly, not sure how I would do that on the FileMaker side, though, either. My plan, up to this point, was the export the file from FileMaker to a known location, then use that location as the input to the JavaScript)

The whole picture: I am trying to create a self contained web-viewer element in FileMaker 12. In FileMaker, I can dynamically define my HTML and JavaScript BEFORE running it.  I want to dynamically hardcode the JavaScript to ALREADY contain the file reference based on the information from the database (i.e. path and filename). This is all running on a local machine, no server involved.

I am trying to minimize the interaction the end user has to make to get the file encoded:  I don't want them to have to put the image into the database, and then also have to drop (or file-chooser) the image again in the web viewer.  I want to keep all of this code inside the FileMaker database to make it much more portable and robust, i.e. not have to rely on an internet connection.  So, the user puts their file into the database, which automatically detects that event, it calculates the JavaScript (including the path to the file), and the JavaScript runs the Base64 function on it, returning the encoded string to the database.

Perhaps I should do it the other way around:  have the user drop the file into a JavaScript area that then copies it into the database.  Not sure that the JavaScript would have any handles for interacting with the database, though.

------------------------   EDIT  (in addition to some tagging and flagging of original question)

Let's ignore the whole FileMaker side of things for now.  I decided to go the route of just using HTML5 and JavaScript as the file input portion (instead of trying to read it in FM and then output to JS).  Just to see if I can get the JavaScript part to work.

Here is some code that I am playing with right now.  It is mostly from the HTML5 Rocks demo, as well as the base64 encoding routine I found.  However, I am running into problems with exactly how to define and call my reader, the onload event, and the encoding function.  Any suggestions would be appreciated:

```
    <script>
    //  From:  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/
    //  JC update:  changing the handleFileSelect() function to do the base64 Processing

  function base64Encode(aFile) {
      /*
       * base64.js - Base64 encoding and decoding functions
       * See: http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM:window.btoa
       *      http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM:window.atob
       * Copyright (c) 2007, David Lindquist <david.lindquist@gmail.com>
       * Released under the MIT license
       *
       * JC, update:  Removed the 'atob' section of code; only need ENcoding, not DEcoding.
       */

      if (typeof btoa == 'undefined') {
          function btoa(str) {
              var chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';
              var encoded = [];
              var c = 0;
              while (c < str.length) {
                  var b0 = str.charCodeAt(c++);
                  var b1 = str.charCodeAt(c++);
                  var b2 = str.charCodeAt(c++);
                  var buf = (b0 << 16) + ((b1 || 0) << 8) + (b2 || 0);
                  var i0 = (buf & (63 << 18)) >> 18;
                  var i1 = (buf & (63 << 12)) >> 12;
                  var i2 = isNaN(b1) ? 64 : (buf & (63 << 6)) >> 6;
                  var i3 = isNaN(b2) ? 64 : (buf & 63);
                  encoded[encoded.length] = chars.charAt(i0);
                  encoded[encoded.length] = chars.charAt(i1);
                  encoded[encoded.length] = chars.charAt(i2);
                  encoded[encoded.length] = chars.charAt(i3);
              }
              return encoded.join('');
          }
      }
  }

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object - a FileList of File objects.
    var fReader = new FileReader () ;  
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      if ( !f.type.match('image.*')) { continue; }    //To skip non-image files
      fReader.onLoad = (function (aFile) { return base64Encode(aFile); } ) (f);
      output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                  '<br><br>' , fReader.readAsBinaryString(f) , '<br><br>', '</li>');
     //This defines the 'onLoad' behavior/function...I think.

    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  function handleDragOver(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
  }

  // Setup the dnd listeners.  [Slightly modified by JC]
  var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
  dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
  dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Comment: You are correct, the `input type=file` is a very specific type of element that is somewhat 'sandboxed' for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

No, in web browsers you can't access arbitrary files on user's computer. Never ever.

You can get files from the network (but read contents only if they are from the same origin or allowed via CORS, and `file://` protocol doesn't allow it), IndexedDB database and Chrome's sandboxed filesystem (which is not user's filesystem — it only contains files you've put there yourself).

And you can create "files" yourself:

```
var file = new Blob(["file content"], {type:"text/plain"})
```

`Blob` is the base class of `File` and it's generally usable everywhere where `input.files[]` is.

You may have privileges to access local files from other JS-based environments like Widgets or browser extensions.

Comment: I kind of like this idea, if it can be done.  But how do I import a file into a new Blob() object?  Text would be simple enough, but an image file?

Comment: Edited my original post; added sample code that I think I have ALMOST working.